# Why do I get an error when trying to create Next app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

I'm trying to learn Next.js but every time I try to create an app I get a network error:request to https registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT
It says I likely have a proxy but I don't think so.
I uninstalled windows and reinstalled it as I had some issues with it.
Now I can't npx create-next-app@latest ./ without getting the above issue. Any help appreciated. I've spent the whole day at this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is related since you don't provide an error message but you can try

```
$ npm config rm proxy
$ npm config rm https-proxy
```

I don't know if it would work

source: https://howtodoinjava.com/angular/npm-install-hung/

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I checked and proxy is null so it's got nothing to do with that. Perhaps there is something I need to let through windows defender?

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I tried the other solutions on that page also. Installed latest version of npm. cleaned the cache. Removed,rebooted and reinstalled node. Proxy is set to null. The only thing I can think of is allowing it through windows defender. I read I should allow Node.js JavaScript Runtime but actually I don't appear to have that. Could that be the issue?